Installed feature_engine & category_encoders via Conda but still getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feature_engine'
I have installed the packages 'feature_engine' & 'category_encoders' via conda
conda list

feature_engine            1.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
category_encoders         2.6.3           py311haa95532_0

But when I try to import these packages, I get the ModuleNotFoundError
from feature_engine.variable_transformers import LogTransformer

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 from feature_engine.variable_transformers import LogTransformer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feature_engine'

import category_encoders

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 import category_encoders

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'category_encoders'

Python Version = 3.11.9
python                    3.11.9               he1021f5_0


I am running Jupyterlab  Version 3.6.7
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py311haa95532_0
jupyter_core              5.7.2           py311haa95532_0


How are you running Python? Did you activate the conda environment? Have you tried restarting the Python interpreter?

Related: Package installed in conda but module not found. How is that possible? (different cause though)

@wjandrea - I am running python via 'jupyter lab'. I have restarted the python interpreter as well as activated the conda activate 'conda activate myenv'

I did > where python
and the output was
C:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\python.exe C:\Anaconda\python.exe C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
